# Starting a game from a different namespace and code file

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, xna-4.0

I have created an XNA game launcher as a Windows form, which allows the user to configure my XNA game before they load it. However, I couldn't find a way to launch the game from a different namespace and directory.

Could you please tell me the code and method to do so?

I was also hoping you could inform me how to export data from features in the form to a XNA game settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean by launching a game from different namespace?

To include namespace, where you game classes reside, just use `using` directive. Like

```
using My.Namespace1;
```

or

```
using MonaGame.MyGameClasses;
```

In C# or the classes, that you declare and write, not matter how they sploit thru the files, are all (typically) belongs to some namespace. So, for your other class (like that Windows form that you're talking about), to see the other classes, if they're in different namespace, of course, all you need to do is to add a reference to a namespace using "using" directive.
By default, all your classes, that you write, are placed into one namespace (at least for Visual Studio IDE), so there must be no problem there.

> I was also hoping if you could inform me in how to export data from
>   features in the form to a Xna game settings file?

There must be some serialization algorithm. Or an exporter. Did you thoroughly searched through documentation?